# Splitting a list of integers into two sublists with the same sum, Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

the query is successful when a list of integers is split into two sublists and both the sublists sum to the same value

an example of a successful query would be:

split([1,1,1,3]).

or

split([15,1,2,3,4,5]).

an unsuccessful would be something like

split([1,2,10]).

Comment: What about `[1,3,1,1]`?

Answer (score 2):

When I'm working on relations between integers, I often use  [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Sublists are contiguous subsequences.

"Exactly two sublists" implies  "prefix / suffix".

Using `append/3` and `sum/3` define `split/1`:

```
split(Xs) :-
   append(Prefix, Suffix, Xs),
   sum(Prefix, #=, Sum),
   sum(Suffix, #=, Sum).
```

Sample queries with SWI-Prolog 8.0.0:

```
?- split([1,1,1,3]).
true ;
false.

?- split([15,1,2,3,4,5]).
true ;
false.

?- split([1,2,10]).
false
```

Two queries succeed<sup>1</sup>, one fails. Like you said they should.

---

**Footnote 1**: Don't worry about getting answers like `true ; false.`—this is how the [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) indicates that Prolog did some backtracking search.